# Python script to search a pattern in a given file

Tags: python

I am looking for a script to search for a file in the directory and grep the content from the file searched. My script here searches for the file `My_data.txt` and I would need to use the same file to open and grep for patter `Name,Age` and want it to be printed.

I am unable to link the below search code to the above one to get my desired script. Please suggest.

```
def search_str(file_path, word):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:

                data = file.read()
                if word in data:
                        print word


search_str(r'/root/convey', 'Name')
```

Ideally, I need a script to search for a file and grep the file to fetch desired data.

Comment: Why use Python, when you already know grep will do the job?

Comment: This is the first part of the script, need to enhance it further to do lot more things from the script. Hence I was looking for some answers around it.

Comment: What is the specific part of the problem you're stuck on? Or are you just looking for recommendations for a library or framework to use?

Answer (score 0):

Not Python: `$ grep -ER -e '{regex expression}' {directory to crawl}` replace items within {}. Or you can do many things with `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Ee ...` to use the powerful `find` features and then pipe those files into a grep command. Don't recreate the wheel.

If I could comment I would have put this there. You have your pieces, i.e. the results in `result`, you could then perform a loop over `result` and in each iteration call search_str on the filename from the iterator.